# Adding window resources to a page?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, windows

I have created a window and set its resources as:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/StyleDark.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I wanted to add a page to the window. I have added the page through the

```
<Frame Source="LoginScreen.xaml"/>
```

The login Screen uses the resources i have added in the window resources.But when i run, the stylesheet is not applied.
I have tried to copy paste the content of page and it works fine. What mistake am I making?